# QGIS Centre Pivot Wheel Vector Height Intersection With Raster

Tags: raster, vector, intersection, analysis

I am trying to visually display a centre pivot irrigator against a DTM Raster file to check terrain clearances in QGIS.  I have a 1m DTM Raster and polygon/and line vector files of the pivot wheels.  Each pivot wheel runs approximately 45m apart there is a 2.5m tower at each wheel point with a straight arm connecting the two.  So at each wheel point as the pivot moves around the wheels will follow the contour/DTM but I want to check that between the two (straight line) there is no intersection with the ground/DTM.  I am struggling to figure out what to convert my vector data to and how to process but I feel there must be a way.

[image]